# Installing SetupTools on VPS Running CentOS 5.4

Tags: python, centos

I am trying to install setuptools via an egg on my VPS. However, I keep getting an error that Python2.6 doesn't exist despite the fact that it is in $PATH:

```
[root@host install]# sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg: line 3: exec: python2.6: not found
[root@host install]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/sbin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/wt_python/bin
[root@host install]# sudo /usr/local/wt_python/bin/python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, May 18 2010, 16:49:22) 
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[root@host install]# sudo python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, May 18 2010, 16:49:22) 
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 ) sudo as root is redundant.
2 ) for a quick hack symlink your python install into a *standardized* path. I'm not 100% familiar with the setuptools installer, but it could spawn a subshell that would mess with environment variables. For that matter sudo depending on flags messes with environment variables.
3) If there isnt a reason why you specifically need a custom python build why not use the one in the repositories?

Hope one or a few of the ideas help.

Rob